# How to call the api/status on a Azure Mobile Service backend using .NET?

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

There's a default StatusController that returns a health status message.

When issuing a GET request to http://localhost:51798/api/status, I get following message:

```
<HealthReport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure/mobileservices">
    <Description>
        The service is considered to be in a healthy state.
    </Description>
    <Health>Healthy</Health>
</HealthReport>
```

I'm using following code in C# console application:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;

MobileServiceClient mobileServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient(AppUrl, AppKey);
var result = await mobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync("status");
```

But, I get a "The request could not be completed. Method not allowed.

How can you get the HealthReport using C# MobileServices client component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the invokeApi method does a POST to the specified API. To do a GET just use one of the other overloads that lets you specify the http method.  This should work for you:

```
var result = await mobileServieClient.InvokeApiAsync("status", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

Comment: Also, by default that will ask for JSON, so you will get { description: text }